# Javascript: Is it possible to memoize a getter by writing a value property to a derived object?

Tags: javascript, properties

Just an idea I had but I cannot get it to work. Simply setting the property "this.length = len" throws an error because there is no setter. Setting the length property descriptor "configurable: true" causes the prototype property to change along with the instance. In this case x and y are undefined in the prototype so length becomes NaN instead of staying a getter like I want. If configurable is false then:

Chromium: Length is set on the derived object. the getter still works on the prototype but it appears as an error value.

FF4: Changes to the getter are silently rejected and length is not set on the derived object.

Here's what I have so far.

```
function Vec2(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Vec2.prototype = Object.create(
  Object.prototype,
  {
    length: {
      get: function length (vec) {
         var len = Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
         Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {value: len});
         return len;
      },
      configurable: true
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: But if you set length then it will no longer be the correct length of x and y, and there's no way to reverse engineer x and y from the length.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was dealing with a value object, which brings up another issue. It would be nice to be able to freeze x and y but still allow extensions to the object to add length. Freeze and seal wont do this. It would be possible to freeze and then clone though, but by now we're talking about enough overhead to likely negate the original purpose.

Comment: Could you do it differently? Instead of trying to overwrite the `length` property with an explicit value, why not just memoize the getter function?